# Can I hook in jsviews to fire my own function when data is linked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsviews

I have found that `jsviews` performs the render at some indeterminate moment in the future after calling `link`. I would like to add some some that relies on the DOM content generated by the template. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not as I suggest. I don't understand my own code.

Comment: JsViews does the render at the time you call the link method. Then if there is data-bound content (data-linked elements - using data-link="..." or tags, using {^{...}}), that content will update synchronously when the underlying data changes. (It must change 'observably'). See all the doc topics on http://www.jsviews.com. Take a look too at all the sample within the content on that site, and the specific samples menu too...